# Relationship mapping in keystone's update scripts

Tags: mongodb, keystonejs

I'm trying to make an update in Keystone with some relation and I cannot get it working. I've been reading the docs and it seems it is ok, also looking for issues here and in GitHub and I cannot find the right answer.

Can anyone help me?

Those are the files:

```
/**update/post.js */
exports.create = {
    Post: [
        { 'name.en': 'Postone', 'name.es': 'Artículo 1'},
        { 'name.en': 'Posttwo', 'name.es': 'Artículo 2'}
    ],
};


/** update/user.js */
exports.create = {
    User: [
        { 'name': 'First User', 'post': 'postone'}
    ]
}
```

The models files are:

User.js

```
    var keystone = require('keystone');
    var async = require('async');
    var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var User = new keystone.List('User', {
    map: {
        name: 'name'
    },
});

User.add({
    name: {
        type: Types.Text,
        initial: true,
        required: true
    },
    post: {
        type: Types.Relationship,
        ref: 'Post',
        many: false
    }
});

User.defaultColumns = 'ID, name, post';
User.register();
```

Post.js

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var async = require('async');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var Post = new keystone.List('Post', {
    map: {
        name: 'name.en'
    },
    autokey: {
        path: 'slug',
        from: 'name.en',
        unique: true
    },
});

Post.add({
    name: {
        en: {
            type: Types.Text,
            initial: true,
            required: true
        },
        es: {
            type: Types.Text
        }
    }
});

Post.relationship({
    path: 'users',
    ref: 'User',
    refPath: 'post'
});

Post.defaultColumns = 'name.en';
Post.register();
```

I'm getting this message:

> Relationship User.post contains an invalid reference: "postone".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See if this modification works:

```
/** update/user.js */
exports.create = {
    User: [
        { 'name': 'First User', 'post': 'Postone'} // replace postone with Postone
    ]
}
```